# Datatable clearing in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I get the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when clearing a data table.

```
Ds.tables["table_name"].Clear();
```

The datatable exists and it contains data.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `tables["table_name"]` resolves to null, so you cant call `Clear()` on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `Ds?.tables["table_name"]?.Clear();`

Comment: Instead of shotgunning null checks all over your code, find out what is null and fix it.

Comment: Did you try the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding.

Comment: Of course i used it but still can't find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's about your object not database, you need to check Ds and then Ds.tables["table_name"] to if they are null then call Ds.tables["table_name"].clear();

Answer (score 0):

Add condition

```
if(Ds.tables["table_name"]!=null){
   Ds.tables["table_name"].Clear();
}
```

OR

```
if(Ds.tables["table_name"]!=null){
   Ds.Rows.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I added the condition and it passes, it's not null.
And the rows.clear() did not work.

Comment: can you check the number of rows present in (Ds.tables["table_name"].Rows.Count)

Comment: I can see the number of rows using the debugger. It contains 5 rows.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the datatable is cleared even if it shows the error msg. The programme does not stop it keeps running.

Comment: then i think its not related with Ds.tables["table_name"] maybe something wrong in app code? or just for a try set it null manually inside if condition "Ds.tables["table_name"] = null;" and try